# Simple Nested expandable bars (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of trouble trying to get a simple nested set of expandable content areas to work. If you were to click on "Project management courses", then click on a sibling (e.g. "IT Courses"), then "Project management courses" should close and "IT Courses" should open.

This needs to also work when nested (i.e. siblings close, then the selected one opens. Any help appreciated!

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfuZc/)**

**HTML**

```
<span class="ui-expand-bar large icon person"><span class="head">Project Management Courses</span></span>
            <div class="content">
                <span class="ui-expand-bar small"><span class="head">Adobe</span></span>
                <div class="content">
                    <table class="plain bullet course-categories">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:45%;">Microsoft Excel Level 1</td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="highlight center"><a href="#">View detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:30%;"><a href="#">View online detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:10%;" class="right"><a class="ui-icon-link-plus" href="/">View</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:45%;">Microsoft Excel Level 1</td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="highlight center"><a href="#">View detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:25%;"><a href="#">View online detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="right"><a class="ui-icon-link-plus" href="/">View</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:45%;">Microsoft Excel Level 1</td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="highlight center"><a href="#">View detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:25%;"><a href="#">View online detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="right"><a class="ui-icon-link-plus" href="/">View</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:45%;">Microsoft Excel Level 1</td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="highlight center"><a href="#">View detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:25%;"><a href="#">View online detail</a></td>
                            <td style="width:15%;" class="right"><a class="ui-icon-link-plus" href="/">View</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <span class="ui-expand-bar open small"><span class="head">Microsoft</span><span class="ui-link-minus">Close</span></span>
            </div>
            <span class="ui-expand-bar large icon computer"><span class="head">IT Courses</span></span>
            <span class="ui-expand-bar large icon cog"><span class="head">Business Skills Courses</span></span>
            <span class="ui-expand-bar large icon person"><span class="head">ELC Re-Settlement Courses</span></span>
            <span class="ui-expand-bar large icon sliders"><span class="head">On-line training Courses</span></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ui-expand-bar').click(function(event) {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings().find('.content').stop().slideUp('200');
        $this.siblings().removeClass('open');        

        if(!$this.hasClass('open')){
            $this.siblings('.ui-expand-bar').find('.content').stop().slideUp('200');
            $this.addClass('open');
            $this.next('.content').stop().slideDown('200');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want

Code:

```
   $('.ui-expand-bar').click(function(event) {
    $this = $(this);
    if($(this).parent('.content').length == 0){    
    $('.content').stop().slideUp('200');
    $this.next('.content').stop().slideToggle('200');
    }else{
     $this.next('.content').stop().slideToggle('200');
    }
    });
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/BfuZc/3/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Thanks, though in your example, when clicking on one of the nested links, the top level item closes. I need the nested links to work also

Comment: Always Welcome Dude :)

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this:

```
$('.ui-expand-bar').click(function(event) {
        $this = $(this);
        //if this not open
        if(!$this.hasClass('open')){
            //close all other siblings
            $this.siblings('.open').removeClass('open');
            $this.siblings('.content').stop().slideUp('200');
            //open this
            $this.addClass('open');
            $this.next('.content').stop().slideDown('200');
        }
        else {
            //thisis open, close it
            $this.removeClass('open');
            $this.next('.content').stop().slideUp('200');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BfuZc/4/ 
i modified the html and the js

Comment: Works very well, maybe slightly better than the accepted answer, so I'll give you a +1 - thanks very much :)